# pretty printing in python

Tags: python

I want to print following lines in a pretty way.

```
Putting a value ... OK
Getting value with only row key ... OK
Getting value with only row key and family... OK
Getting value with only row key and family and qualifier... OK
Getting value with row key which is not put... OK
```

I want all the `OK` should be in one column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lines = ['Putting a value ...',
         'Getting value with only row key ...',
         'Getting value with only row key and family...',
         'Getting value with only row key and family and qualifier...',
         'Getting value with row key which is not put...']

for line in lines:
  print '%-59s' % line,
  # ...
  print 'OK'
```

This prints

```
Putting a value ...                                         OK
Getting value with only row key ...                         OK
Getting value with only row key and family...               OK
Getting value with only row key and family and qualifier... OK
Getting value with row key which is not put...              OK
```

For this work, you need to know the length of the longest string (`59` in the example above).

Comment: you could calculate the width automatically: `width = max(map(len, lines))`. To use it: `"%-*s" % (width, line)` or `"{:{}}".format(line, width)`